# How do I import and use module using core JS in NativeScript

Tags: javascript, nativescript, node-modules

### Problem: Using NPM Modules From NativeScript using Core Javascript

I am new to NativeScript and am trying to use the FancyAlert NPM module:

https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-fancyalert

In their readme, they show a very simple example using TypeScript, like this:

```
import { TNSFancyAlert, TNSFancyAlertButton } from "nativescript-fancyalert";
.
.
.
public showSuccess() {
    TNSFancyAlert.showSuccess(
      "Success!",
      "Fancy alerts are nice.",
      "Yes they are!"
    );
  }
```

and in their XML file, they simply call it like normal:

```
 <Button text="Alert Success" tap="{{showSuccess}}" />
```

### How to convert that to core JS

So I am not using TypeScript. I cannot get this simple alert to work. I have tried:

in my **main-view-model.js**

```
const fancyAlert = require("nativescript-fancyalert");

.
.
.

fancyAlert.showSuccess(
                    "Success!",
                    "You are logged in.",
                    "Success!"
                  );
```

not working.

Can anyone help me to use this module using core JS?

Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-fancyalert/issues/24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `fancyAlert.TNSFancyAlert.showSuccess()`.

**[EDIT]** This really should work, as it's a mirror of the solution given in the [issue filing](https://github.com/NathanWalker/nativescript-fancyalert/issues/24) linked by Narendra Mongiya in your question. One thing to keep in mind is that it's a Promise, so let's add a `catch()` block in there to reveal any errors.

```
const fancyAlert = require("nativescript-fancyalert");

// ...

fancyAlert.TNSFancyAlert.showSuccess(
    "Success!",
    "You are logged in.",
    "Success!"
)
.then((resolution) => {
    console.log("[TNSFancyAlert] showSuccess() succeeded.", resolution);    
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.error("[TNSFancyAlert] showSuccess() failed.", error);
});
```

You may also find that you're simply calling it from the wrong place in your code.

Comment: @JohnS. I've edited for clarification; how about now?

Comment: @JohnS. I notice that in your JS example, the context of the fancy alert call is unclear; you are wrapping that inside a `showSuccess` function, right? Bear in mind that you have to bind `showSuccess` properly between the XML and the JS file in order for it to work. See the [Data Binding](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/data-binding#binding-to-a-plain-object) documentation for more examples (in both TypeScript and JavaScript). You can also refer to [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html) to convert any TS snippets you find elsewhere to JS.

Comment: first , thanks so much for taking your time to try to help me.  Now, this is weird.... I used your code, and the app runs, but no alert, and no error either. Here it is on the PlayGround:  https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=vCLv25&v=2  

Do you see where I am going wrong here??

Comment: Your playground is showing error, ERROR: [TNSFancyAlert] showSuccess() failed. ReferenceError: Can't find variable: SCLAlertView